# Javascript function return value is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've the following code. The return value of the function `get_last_catergory_value` is always `undeifned`. I've searched stackoverflow but couldn't debug the issue.

When I show the value being returned just before the `return` statement it shows the correct value. But when it is returned from function it is `undefined`. Can you please help me to resolve this?

```js
function fetch_product(brand) {
 var brand = brand;

 //get last category id
 var last_category = 'subcategory10';

 var last_category_value = get_last_catergory_value(last_category);
 alert(last_category_value); //undefined
}

function get_last_catergory_value(last_category) {

 if($('.' + last_category).find(':selected').val() == 'none') {

  last_category_number = last_category.substring(11);
  last_category_number = parseInt(last_category_number);
  last_category_number--;

  last_category = last_category.substring(0, 11);
  last_category = last_category + last_category_number;
  get_last_catergory_value(last_category);  //recall the function with values 'subcategory9', 'subcategory8' and so on...
 } else {
  var value = $('.' + last_category).find(':selected').val();

  alert(value); //Gives the correct value here
  return value;
 }
}
```

Forgive me if its a trivial issue. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you're missing a `return` on the recursive call.

Comment: thanks. that solved the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

return statement is missing in the if block of get_last_catergory_value(last_category)

```
 function get_last_catergory_value(last_category) {

if($('.' + last_category).find(':selected').val() == 'none') {

    last_category_number = last_category.substring(11);
    last_category_number = parseInt(last_category_number);
    last_category_number--;

    last_category = last_category.substring(0, 11);
    last_category = last_category + last_category_number;
    return get_last_catergory_value(last_category);
} else {
    var value = $('.' + last_category).find(':selected').val();

    alert(value); //Gives the correct value here
    return value;
}
}
```